# img srcset picking 1x on iMac 5k display

Tags: css, html, srcset

I want to create a fullwidth bootstrap slider, and I need it to work on 5k iMacs, so i went on and add my image like this:
`<img srcset="http://placehold.it/1920x800 1x, http://placehold.it/3840x1600 2x, http://placehold.it/5120x2130 4x" alt="Retina" />`, but chrome loaded the **1x** image.

After some googling, I did this: `<img srcset="http://placehold.it/1920x800 1920w, http://placehold.it/3840x1600 3840w, http://placehold.it/5120x2130 5120w" alt="Retina" />`, and chrome picked the **3840w** image, it filled fine, but this syntax (using **w**) wont work on Safari, and, as you may guess, I need safari support.

Is the 5k iMac display considered 1x? If so, can some polifill solve my problem?

**Edit:** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joaobeno/u4c25rsr/8/embedded/result/)

Comment: What DPI setting is the 5K iMac running at?

Comment: 2560 x 1440 (Retina)

Comment: I tried on a non-retina 27', both does the same, picking the 1920 image instead of the bigger ones...

Comment: Please produce as jsFiddle example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I did a fiddle, but I can't test it on the Macs tonight, but i think these should yield the same results...